# Половина Bitmap'а

Tags: java, android, изображения, bitmap

Мне нужен специфический Bitmap: из всего Bitmapa мне нужно вырезать половину (нижнюю), как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть некоторый код, но этот код создает эффект зеркала на половине Bitmapa, а мне просто нужна нижняя часть. 
Возможно, проблема в том, что я делаю 2 матрицы?

```
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(0.1f, 0.1f);
    int width = mainimage.getWidth();
    int height = mainimage.getHeight();
    int w = width/2;
    int h = height/2;

    Matrix matrix_flip = new Matrix();
    matrix_flip.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
    Bitmap all = Bitmap.createBitmap(mainimage, 0, 0,    mainimage.getWidth(), mainimage.getHeight(), matrix_flip, true);

    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.preScale(-1, 1);

    Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(all, 0, 0, width, h, matrix, true);



    ImageView mforblur = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_copy);
    mforblur.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
```

Или есть способ проще?

Comment: проще это понятие растяжимое, мне может двойным циклом проще пройтись :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден.

```
        int width = mainimage.getWidth();
        int height = mainimage.getHeight();
        int w = width/2;
        int h = height/2;
        int halfWidth = width - w;
        int halfHeight = height - h;

         Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mainimage, 0, h, width, halfHeight);
         ImageView mforblur = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_copy);
         mforblur.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
         mforblur.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Answer (score -1):

Возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону PorterDuff - хорошая статья по теме https://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/1009/
Для ваших целей думаю подойдет PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR)

Comment: спасибо за совет. Но, все же, можно ли это сделать штатными средствами? Мне кажется, что это должно быть не таким уж сложным делом, правда, сам не могу пока понять, как

Comment: А это и есть штатные средства, входят в Android SDK :) Чем вам не нравится такой вариант? вот есть ответ с примером http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432495/cut-the-portion-of-bitmap